# Difference between mkdir and CreateDirectory

Tags: winapi, mkdir, create-directory

Is there a difference between `mkdir(<name>)` and `CreateDirectory(<name>, NULL)` under Win32.

As I can see, both are working (in the same way ??)

Comment: Off the top of my head, doesn't one create intermediate subdirectories too, while the other doesn't?

Comment: @MrLister Nope, both of them fail if intermediate subdirectories don't exist. However, `mkdir` is deprecated and `CreateDirectory` allows security descriptors. [`SHCreateDirectoryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762131%28VS.85%29.aspx) is maybe the one you were thinking of for creating intermediates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mkdir` (and the recommended [_mkdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx) are runtime library functions. `CreateDirectory` is specific to Windows. If you want portable code, call `_mkdir`. If you're fine making your program Windows-specific, or you need the ability to add security descriptors, then call `CreateDirectory`.

Most likely, the `_mkdir` implementation for Windows calls `CreateDirectory(name, NULL)`. So both end up doing the same thing.

Edit: The Visual Studio 12 implementation of _mkdir() calls _wmkdir(), which then calls CreateDirectoryW:

```
int __cdecl _wmkdir (
        const wchar_t *path
        )
{
        ULONG dosretval;

        /* ask OS to create directory */

        if (!CreateDirectoryW(path, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL))
            dosretval = GetLastError();
        else
            dosretval = 0;

        if (dosretval) {
            /* error occured -- map error code and return */
            _dosmaperr(dosretval);
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
}
```